# Why does errno set EAGAIN if I use O_NDELAY? read from dev/tty

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I have this:

```
//...
      if ((tty = open("/dev/tty",O_RDONLY | O_NDELAY) ) == -1 )
        {
                perror("/dev/tty");
                return 1;
        }
        //...
        if (-1 == (fi = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) )
        {
                perror(argv[1]);
                return 1;
        }
        //...
        while (1)
        {
                printf("you have five seconds to enter a line number %d", line); 
                sleep(5);
                i = read(tty, buf, 257);
                printf("read %d\n", i);
                if ( i == -1) {
                        perror("dev/tty/"); 
                        // if nothing was entered read always returns -1
                        //and perror prints: Resource temporarily unavailable. it's STRANGE!!!
                }
                if ( i == 0 )
                {
                        lseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET);
                        while((i = read(fi, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0) 
                              write(1, buf, i);
                        return 0;
                }
                //...
                if ( 0 == read(fi, buf, lines_length[line]))
                {
                        fprintf(stderr,"can't read\n");
                        return 1;
                }
                write(1, buf, lines_length[line]);
        }
 //...
```

So I open /dev/tty with O_NDELAY flag, but it seems something wrong because later read returns -1 (it must return 0).  I can't find out what's wrong. 
  And one more question: why does **printf("you have 5 sec")** print after **write(1, buf, lines_length[line]);**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if nothing was entered read always returns -1 and perror prints:
>   Resource temporarily unavailable. it's STRANGE!!!

That's precisely what `O_NDELAY` is supposed to do. It doesn't wait for the read operation to finish. If it can't be performed at once, instead of blocking it returns `-1` and sets `errno = EAGAIN`.

---

As for your second question, you're not flushing output. Try: `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: for terminal does it do it too?

Comment: @greensher When you pass `O_NDELAY` `open` tries to make the descriptor nonblocking, without regard to the type of object it opens. Some object types may not support nonblocking operation - from your example it seems `tty`s do.

Comment: @greensher That's right, I was thinking of `EAGAIN` and typed `EINTR`, sorry.

Comment: @greensher Give us a better perspective. What are you trying to achieve ? Why do you pass `O_NDELAY` in the first place ?

Comment: my university course's of operating systems tutorial (textboook) says that work with terminal : "Если не будет ввода, то функции read(2) вернется с нулем." (If nothing was entered then read returns 0); so can you give me a proofs that read returns -1?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25907/discussion-between-greensher-and-cnicutar)

Answer (score 1):

In early versions of UNIX System for non-blocking operations was used flag O_NDELAY. if O_NDELAY was set, then read returned 0. Since it contradicts Unix convention ( returned 0 indicates end of file), POSIX.1 defined flag of non-blocking mode - O_NONBLOCK. Nowadays flag O_NDELAY is used only for compatibility and shouldn't be used in modern applications.